# Why Windows 8/AnkhSVN remove permissions?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, ankhsvn

I am using `Windows 8 Pro`, `Visual Studio 2012` and `AnkhSVN`.

The problem is: when I update my solution using SVN, Windows, AnkhSVN, VS or anything else changes the permission of that file. So when I run the project I get permission denied.

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC3 project and using the local IIS 8 as my server.

I've researched and solved the problem by giving permission for my local users. But I don't want to do that for every time I update my solution.

What could be done to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you tried to set permissions per files or for whole folder?

Comment: @outcoldman I did it for files the first time and after for the folder. Both ways worked.

Comment: You should try set permission for parent folder of the folder where you have SVN enlistment. Also you can try to change User for your Application Pool, so it will be launched by your user (it is not good for security, but if this is only for your dev box, this should work).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Post that as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First suggestion:
You should try set permission for parent folder of the folder where you have SVN enlistment. Then all folders / files should inherit permissions from parent folder.

Second suggestion:
Also you can try to change User for your Application Pool, so it will be launched by your user. It is not good for security, but if this is only for your dev box, this should work.